# Switching between Forms in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, showdialog

When the autogenerated code for my program starts, it calls

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

and starts `Form1`.  I have another form I'd like to switch to and close `Form1` at the same time.  The problem is if I use `this.Close()` in `Form1` before I call the other form with `Form.ShowDialog()` then the program ends.  If I put it after `ShowDialog` then it remains up in the background until I close `Form2`, at which point the program ends.

How can I spawn a copy of `Form2` while closing the currently opened frame at the same time?

**Edit:**  I have tried calling `Form2` with `.Show()` as well, but the new frame closes instantly.

Comment: if Form2 is called by Form1 as modal form with ShowDialog why do you want to hide the calling form?

Comment: Davide, actually I would like to call it modelessly with Show but the window closes immediately.

Comment: Ive amended my answer to show you how to modify the message loop for modeless forms.

Answer (score 9):

The following solution works as you expect.

To try this sample code, create a new WinForms application in Visual Studio (i.e. File --> New Project, select Visual C# --> Windows Classic Desktop and use the template "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)"), then add a 2<sup>nd</sup> form.

Ensure the two forms are named as `Form1` and `Form2`, then modify the code in the generated solution as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormClosed += 
           new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosed);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        (new Form2()).Show();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormClosed += 
           new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.Form2_FormClosed);
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

And this is the entry point of the application, modify it as follows:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        //Show first form and start the message loop
        (new Form1()).Show();
        Application.Run(); // needed, otherwise app closes immediately
    }

}
```

The trick is to use Application.Run() without parameters and Application.Exit() at the point where you want to exit the application.

Now when you run the application, `Form1` opens up. Click on the **<kbd>X</kbd>** (upper right corner) and Form1 closes, but `Form2` appears instead. Click on the **<kbd>X</kbd>** again and the form closes (and exits the application too).

Instead of placing the launch of `Form2` into the FormClosed event, you could also create a button <kbd>Button1</kbd> which does the job, but in that case don't forget to close the form to which the button belongs to via `this.Close()` explicitly:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new Form2()).Show(); this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to call `this.Hide()` which makes it invisible but still open, instead of `this.Close()` which closes it (and seeing as it is the main form of the application, closes the application too).

Comment: If I hide the Form, how do I get back to it from Form2 when I'm done there?  I can't called Form1.Show() from inside the Form2 methods?

Comment: @rumsey: ShowDialog will wait until Form2 is shut, so after the call to ShowDialog(), call this.Show().

Comment: Just hiding it keeps it in memory, which is ok if you want to re-open it later. Otherwise it is better to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Found this question and a [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7536/How-To-Swap-Top-Level-Forms) on the same google.

The author basically creates a top-level form that manages switching between the forms he wants to show.